# Es posible subir archivos binarios al servidor mediante un web service REST.¿Cómo?

Tags: php, laravel-5, rest

Actualmente estoy trabajando el desarrollo de un sistema web con Laravel 5.

En este momento, necesito subir archivos binarios (pdf, imágenes, etc.) Pero sin utilizar formularios web.

Mi consulta es: ¿es posible realizar esto con un web service  REST?

Entiendo que se puede hacer codificando el archivo binario en base64 pero desconozco si esta es la forma más correcta o si existe una forma más eficiente de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) que te permite enviar información como si fuera un formulario, pero sin el formulario. Tienes que saber algunas cosas (como la URL de destino, el método usado y los parámetros necesarios), pero a partir de ahí es (casi) como cualquier otra llamada AJAX:

- Crea una variable de la clase FormData
- Añádele el fichero que haya seleccionado el usuario
- Realiza la petición con AJAX

El código sería así (variación de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690647/3695983) a una pregunta parecida en StackOverflow):

```
var misDatos = new FormData();
misDatos.append('fichero', subirfichero.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'carga.php',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false, // importante o recibirás un fallo de seguridad
  contentType: false, // importante o recibirás un fallo de seguridad
  dataType : 'json',
  data: misDatos
});
```

Como mencionas, también podrías codificar el fichero en base 64 y mandarlo de ese modo. Eso funcionaría, pero [los archivos codificados ocuparán hasta un 40% más del tamaño original](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME), lo que puede no ser muy conveniente si el fichero es muy grande.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue muy útil tu respuesta!